# Synchronize clients of a Flask application with websockets

Tags: python, flask

I've followed this simple tutorial on sync two clients on flask, I'm running it locally but opening two tabs of "localhost" do not make my sliders sync.

https://www.matthieuamiguet.ch/blog/synchronize-clients-flask-application-websockets

I am working on pycharm, on a venv.

- Python 3.9
- Flask-SocketIO 4.3.1
- Flask 2.0.1

I get "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

I tried both debug mode on and off.

Code below:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")

values = {
    'slider1': 25,
    'slider2': 0,
}

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', **values)

@socketio.on('value changed')
def value_changed(message):
    values[message['who']] = message['data']
    emit('update value', message, broadcast=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0')
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Synchronized Sliders</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var socket = io.connect();

            socket.on('connect', function() {
                socket.emit('connect', {data: 'I\'m connected!'});
            });

            $('input.sync').on('input', function(event) {
                socket.emit('value changed', {who: $(this).attr('id'), data: $(this).val()});
                return false;
            });

            socket.on('update value', function(msg) {
                $('input#'+msg.who).val(msg.data)
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Synchronized Sliders!</h1>

    <input id="slider1" class="sync" type="range" min="0" max="50" value="{{slider1}}" /> <br>
    <input id="slider2" class="sync" type="range" min="0" max="50" value="{{slider2}}" />

    <input id="txt1" class="sync" type="text" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some update: I added as additional options when running: --host myip --port ####, I am able to access from another computer inside my local network, but the slider does not sync.

Comment: what is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: According to the tutorial, one should be able to modify a slider in one client and see it reflected on the other, it should update without the need to refresh the page. I don't see any change. Not even by refreshing.

Comment: Is there any error message in console or in terminal?

Comment: There is not. This is my output

Comment: myip - - [16/Jul/2021 19:09:55] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
myip - - [16/Jul/2021 19:09:55] "GET /socket.io/1/?t=########## HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by replacing on the index.html

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

by

```
var socket = io.connect(my ip);
```

You can check it by typing ipconfig on a cmd window and setting the number from the IPv4 Address.